# Class session not found while not using session

Tags: php, laravel-5

The problem is that I'm reciving `Class 'session' not found` error.
But the funny fact is that I'm not using session class. Anyway I'm using session namespace `use Session;`. I've found out that the problem occurs when I'm **returning view**.

If I return simple string or number it works, but when I use

```
return view('catering.prices')->with(['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

or

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

I'm reciving the error.

Log:

```
    [2016-10-06 11:38:54] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'session' not found' in D:\app\storage\framework\views\397c6d5694d7a10e04cabd271a3359cfd11a387e.php:16
```

**Update**
I'm seeing that it's not returning new views - I have now about 40 views. The old one are working well but when I create new views I'm reciving the error.

**Answer**
The problem was wrongly set permissions for specific user in my database. Thank you for your effort.

Anybody has some idea?

Comment: please enable debug mode in Laravel and provide full info of exception.

Comment: Is my reply worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
return view('catering.prices',['name'=> 'Victoria']);
```

OR

```
return view('catering.prices')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```

check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your solution is not working. That's very strange what's happening.